# WebStorm 2017.1.1 StandardJS not working

Tags: format, coding-style, webstorm, standards, eslint

In WebStorm 2017.1.1 there's an integration with StandardJS. The problem is that it's not working for me on Mac and/or Windows:

[image: Screenshot #1]

[image: Screenshot #2]

Any thoughts?

Standard package is installed globally. StandardJS works fine in VSCode with it's own plugin (which might use `npm`'s `standard` package, not sure)

> Standard Code Style: Can not find package.json under '/'

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly ... it expects to find `package.json` in the project root folder ... but accordingly to your screenshot you have it in ReduxSimpleStarter subfolder. I say: make new project where `ReduxSimpleStarter` will the the root folder and try again. No other ideas from my end.

Comment: Did it already. Also - used standard from package.json (project, not global) - doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a **.eslint.rc** in the project's root that was there prior to Webstorm's release that featured Standard. The closest relative .eslint.rc is used, hence the error message that the "package.json can't be found in /"

Once I deleted my project's root .eslint.rc and:

1. npm i -D standard
2. set Webstorm's "**Language & Frameworks > Javascript > Code Quality Tools > ESLint**" to **/node_modules/standard**

The error disappeared. Hope that information is helpful.

Comment: Don't know why, but disabling and enabling it again using global standard package works fine.

I didn't have eslintrc file.

http://i.imgur.com/uyOP9du.png http://i.imgur.com/AXPmx1z.png